# CSS in Freemarker spring.formInput

Tags: html, css, spring, freemarker

I am trying to apply css to this ftl snippet:

```
<@spring.formInput "customer.email" />
```

the CSS I am using is:

```
.card.alt .input-container input {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.card.alt .input-container input:focus ~ label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.card.alt .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:before, .card.alt .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.card.alt .input-container input:valid ~ label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.card.alt .input-container label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.card.alt .input-container .bar {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

This works when it was plain HTML with  but I am not sure how to get the CSS to apply to <@Spring..> tag

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot be applied to FreeMarker tags, because they are processed by FreeMarker engine and removed in the output (which is mostly HTML).

```
<@spring.formInput "customer.email" />
```

will render something like:

```
<input type="text" name="customer.email" />
```

So you should prepare your styles for the resulting tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style class to the input using:

<@spring.formInput "customer.email" "class='inputClass'"/>

Then you can use inputClass in you CSS.